# 'expected 2-element int8 array' error while getting data from continuous aggregate in timescale db (Using query with subquery)

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am having table with mac_address and uptime. Mac address will be given with colon or without colon. I am having the following data

```
 mac_address   |      timestamp      | uptime
-------------------+---------------------+----------
AA:BB:45:TT:CC:34 | 2020-11-30 00:00:04 |    0
112233445566      | 2020-11-30 00:00:06 |    0
NN:CC:33:33:22:22 | 2020-11-30 00:00:05 |    0
AA:BB:45:TT:CC:34 | 2020-11-30 00:30:04 |    1
112233445566      | 2020-11-30 00:30:06 |    1
NN:CC:33:33:22:22 | 2020-11-30 00:30:05 |    1
```

I have created an hourly continous agggregate view to get average uptime in each hour using below query

```
CREATE VIEW aggregated_data
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT
time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 hour', timestamp) AS time_bucket,
mac_address,
AVG(uptime) AS avg_uptime
FROM data_table
GROUP BY time_bucket, mac_address
```

When I am trying to get data from aggregated_data table using below query, I am getting error '**expected 2-element int8 array**'

```
SELECT mac_address, time_bucket,
avg_uptime, count(*) over() as count
FROM aggregated_data
WHERE time_bucket >= '2020-10-28 18:00:00' and time_bucket < '2020-11-30 08:31:52'
AND mac_address IN (
          SELECT mac_address
          FROM aggregated_data
          WHERE time_bucket >= '2020-11-28 18:00:00' and time_bucket < '2020-11-30 08:31:52'
          GROUP BY mac_address
          HAVING AVG(avg_uptime) > 0 AND AVG(avg_uptime) <=10
  )
ORDER BY time_bucket LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I have created the table using below query

```
CREATE TABLE data_table (     
        mac_address VARCHAR(20),     
        timestamp TIMESTAMP,     
        uptime INT 
);
```

I have created the hyper table using

```
SELECT create_hypertable('data_table','timestamp');
```

We have nearly 3000 records. They are materialized.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the table and the hypertable? How much data was inserted? Were they materialized in the continuous aggregate?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you added it to the issue, so the question is complete? Also can you post how you created the hypertable?

Comment: Thank you @k_rus for your reply
Following are the table details  

```CREATE TABLE data_table
(
    mac_address VARCHAR(20),
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    uptime INT
);```  


```SELECT create_hypertable('data_table','timestamp');```  


We have nearly 3000 records. They are materialized.